# Помогите завести AndEngine в Android Studio 0.2.8

Tags: java, android-studio, andengine

Привет всем!
В общем, Как Я понимаю, механизм добавления новых модулей в андроид студио 0.2.8 изменился.

Пытаюсь подключить andEngine пользуясь [этим](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fcSowvlKMqfTjM9r1mMP48KEhWbkJZGBDR5duFg4QYc/edit) мануалом, но скомпилить проект мне не удается, в лог вываливается сообщение с ошибкой:

```
/home/username/devel/java/HellProject/AndEngine/build.gradle
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':AndEngine'.
> Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.7
```

Гуру андройд разработки, помогите пожалуйста разобраться мне, полному нубасу в этом деле)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А это

> Gradle version 1.6 is required.
> Current version is 1.7

ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: Говорит, но Я не понимаю, в какую сторону копать. Когда Я создаю проект, он компилится, и запускается хоть на девайсе, хоть на эмуляторе. Но когда создаю новый модуль, он начинает так ругаться.
Разные компоненты одного проекта собираются разными версиями gradle? O_o

Comment: Посмотрите ссылку, тут что-то похожее:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659145/gradle-version-1-6-is-required-current-version-is-1-8-201307302200350000